# Form does only work the second time it is submitted

Tags: ajax, forms, smoothstate.js

The first time I try to submit a form the form is not submitted. The page however does refresh but is reloaded. However the second time I hit the form button the form works because the page is reloaded.

The code is on the following page:

http://theloop.nl/hyperactie/waar/

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

it seems that my smoothstate code was the problem:

```
forms: 'form',
blacklist: '.slick-prev',
blacklist: '.slick-next',
blacklist: '#mobile-menu',
blacklist: '.no-smoothstate',
blacklist: 'form',
```

Changed it to:

```
forms: 'form',
blacklist: '.slick-prev, .slick-next, #mobile-menu, .no-smoothstate, form',
```

And now it works.